# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: id #[0].IsSocial

Tags: jquery

I have id="[0].IsSocial".But i want to select element,i have issue

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: id #[0].IsSocial
```

**Update**
jquery

```
        $('[name=[0].IsSocial]').on('change', function () {
        alert('Вы нажали на элемент "foo"');
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#[" + @i + "].socialSurface").css("display", "block");
        } else {
            $("#[" + @i + "].socialSurface").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
```

html element

```
<input name="[0].IsSocial">
```

Comment: You need to be more clear about what code are you using and where is `[0].IsSocial` in your code.

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
 $('[name=[0].IsSocial]').on('change', function () {
```

with:

```
$("input[name='[0].IsSocial']").on('change', function () {
```